# Pre-Selection of LinkedHashMap in selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf

To create a new user, the admin can select a role in my create-view via a `selectOneMenu`. Therefore I have these lines:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="role" value="#{creationBacking.createdUser.role}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{creationBacking.roles}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

In my `CreationBacking` I init the Map:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    createdUser = new User();
    roles = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    roles.put("User", 1);
    roles.put("Admin", 0);
}
```

Since it is a `LinkedHashMap` the order in the droptown is User first, then Admin, but unfortunately the *pre-selection* is Admin. I guess because of the value 0. Can I somehow easily force in the view that the pre-selection is the first item of the `Map`, e.g. the first item in the dropdown (without changing the values)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre select role by setting creationBacking.createdUser.role in your init().

Comment: Wow. Really didn't expect, that this works. But it does :-)